# $P$ and $Q$ are unitarily equivalent iff dimensions of ranges and kernels are the same

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Two projections $P,Q$ are unitarily equivalent if and only if 
$$dim(randP)=dim(ranQ)$$
$$dim(kerP)=dim(kerQ)$$

How can we show this? One directionn seems easy:

If $P$ and $Q$ are unitarily eqv, then $PU=UQ$ where $U$ is an isomorphism,hence preserves the dimension of the Hilbert space. Therefore, $dimranP=dimranQ$.

How to show the other direction? Please help me with this.

Comment: It's false.${}$

Comment: Are you assuming your projections are orthogonal projections (equivalently, that they are self-adjoint)?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, aren't projections always self adjoint?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Maybe you could elaborate a little on your answer?

Comment: A projection is just a linear operator $P$ such that $P^2 = P$, it need not even be continuous, let alone self-adjoint. But it's not quite uncommon that when considering projections on Hilbert spaces, one restricts the attention to self-adjoint projections, and omits the qualification, since one doesn't consider other projections. That's why I asked. (And it's even more common to omit the "continuous" qualification when one only considers continuous projections.)

Comment: If we considered (continuous) projections that aren't self-adjoint, the assertion would be false. I suppose the dimension means the cardinality of a Hilbert basis here, for if it meant the algebraic dimension (cardinality of a Hamel basis), it would be wrong too. So, orthogonal projections, and Hilbert dimension; then it's true. Consider what it means that two (sub)spaces have the same Hlbert dimension.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, it makes sense now! 
Do you have any ideas/hints how to show converse of this statement?