# Equivalent Condition of Unitary Equivalence of Projections in a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

This question is Exercise 2.10 in Rordam's *K-Theory for C$^{*}$-Algebras* book. Let $p,q$ be projections in an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space.

> Show that $p$ and $q$ are unitarily equivalent (i.e., $\exists$ unitary $u\in H$ with $q=upu^{*}$) if and only if $\dim(p(H))=\dim(q(H))$ and $\dim(p(H)^{\perp})=\dim(q(H)^{\perp})$.

This question was asked once before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271363/p-and-q-are-unitarily-equivalent-iff-dimensions-of-ranges-and-kernels-are-th), but no answer was given.

I have solved the first part of the problem, which asks to show that $p$ and $q$ are equivalent in the Murray von-Neumann sense iff $\dim(p(H))=\dim(q(H))$. Since in a C$^{*}$-algebra unitary equivalence implies Murray von-Neumann equivalence, the forward direction reduces to showing $\dim(p(H)^{\perp})=\dim(q(H)^{\perp})$. But I am stuck in excluding the case where $\dim(p(H))$ and $\dim(q(H))$ are co-finite with $\dim(H)\setminus\dim(p(H))\not=\dim(H)\setminus\dim(q(H))$ I have thought about this question for hours, but I am at a loss as to how to proceed. I would really appreciate any help with completing the forward implication and with obtaining the reverse implication.

Thank you.

Comment: These are hermitian projections, right?

Comment: Yes. They are hermetian.

Comment: Find Hilbert basises and of $p(H)$, $q(H)$ and extend these to Hilbert basises of all of $H$. Can you see how to define a sensible $U$?

Comment: I thought about doing this, but did not figure out how to define $U$.

Comment: How to prove $p,q$ are equivalent iff $dim(p(H))=dim(q(H))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{e_i\mid i\in I_1\}$ be a Hilbert basis of $p(H)$ and $\{b_i\mid i\in I_1\}$ be a Hilbert basis of $q(H)$, note that the index set is the same, this follows from $\mathrm{dim}\,p(H)=\mathrm{dim}\,q(H)$.

Extend these to Hilbert basises $\{e_i\mid i\in I_2\}$ and $\{b_i\mid i\in I_2\}$. Again the index sets are the same, which follows from $\mathrm{dim}\,(1-q)(H) = \mathrm{dim}\,q(H)^\perp=\mathrm{dim}\,p(H)^\perp=\mathrm{dim}\,(1-p)(H)$.

The map
$$U:H\to H,\quad \sum_{i\in I_2} x_i e_i\mapsto \sum_{i\in I_2} x_i b_i$$
is unitary. Note that:
$$Up\left(\sum_{i\in I_2} x_i e_i\right) = U\left(\sum_{i\in I_1} x_i e_i\right)=\sum_{i\in I_1}x_ib_i = q\left(\sum_{i\in I_2}x_i b_i\right)=qU\left(\sum_{i\in I_2}x_i e_i\right) $$

so $Up=qU$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Might you also tell me how to prove that remaining part of the forward implication; i.e., that if $p\sim_{u} q$, then $\dim(p(H))^{\perp}=\dim(q(H))^{\perp}$?

Comment: I was thinking of maybe defining an isomorphism from $(1-q)(H)\to(1-p)(H)$, using the fact that the two projections are unitarily equivalent, but I'm not sure how to do this, or if this is the way to go.

Comment: From the hermiticity of $p$ and $q$ you know that $(1-q)(H)=q(H)^\perp$ and the same with $p$. Further then $U(1-p)(H)=(U-Up)(H)=(U-qU)(H)=(1-q)U(H)$ so the unitary $U$ also sends $p(H)^\perp$ to $q(H)^\perp$. Unitary maps preserve dimension of subspaces.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I just figured that last part out a minute before you typed it!